# ASP.NET MVC 2: Emulating eBay Postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, postback

Below is an image of the sections I'm talking about:
[image]

What I'm doing is very similar to eBay:

1) a form at the top for "search terms" and then a category.

2) filters on the left that a user can click to refine the search even further.

3) sorting those results.

I played with eBay a bit and it looks to me like they are posting back every time a filter (box on the left) is clicked, or when they sort the results. Do they then store a copy of all the "settings" used to display the page in the form and use that to post back on a submit click?

How can I emulate this functionality? I don't like the idea of wrapping an entire page in a `form` element... it seems dirty. Should I use jQuery to collect all of the user input and then somehow pass it along?

Comment: @Nathan, I'm not asking anyone to write code for me. That is extremely presumptuous... I am genuinely stumped as to how to best accomplish this. I'm using eBay as an example, clearly: "what I'm doing is very similar to ebay"

Comment: I'm sorry if it seemed presumptuous, but from the text of your question I got the impression you wanted to wrap eBay. My mistake.

Comment: @Nathan, understood. Honestly, I'm just trying to figure out how I can collect all of this user input (from some form elements, clicked links, sorts, etc) and throw it all back at my controller. I just can't wrap my head around the "right way" of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided that the best solution is to use jQuery Ajax. Otherwise, I'd have to make sure that every peice of user input is a `form` element and wrap the entire page in a `form` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how eBay does it, but if it were me, I'd have some javascript object that keeps track of all the search options on the page. Each of the elements you've highlighted would fire an event that would cause my javascript object to update this information, send it via AJAX to a controller action, and update the results area with the changes.

That's a somewhat simplified version of events, but hopefully it can put you on the right track.

Comment: That is pretty much what I'm been thinking. Is that that only option though? It seems to me that there should be an "MVC proper" way of doing things like this...

Comment: If you wanted to do this without using AJAX, you could have your search action take all of the potential search options as parameters, pass those options to the View code, and set up each call to Html.ActionLink() to use all the current parameters plus the parameter related to clicking that particular button. That way the URL would include all of your previous search options, plus the one you just clicked on.

Comment: Yeah, the only problem is that the options are dynamic and can't be predicted in a Model or a static set of parameters.

Comment: They're not that dynamic. There's selected category (int), a search term (string), and a sort parameter (enum).

Comment: Well maybe on eBay, but within my application, there's no way of know exactly what "filters" will be there... it's quite dynamic and only revealed when the call to the DB is made.

Comment: I use a strongly typed object - SearchOptions which stores any filter along with the page number etc. I then update that object with any new query string parameters when I get a request.